# STAR song in spotify through AHK

Tags: autohotkey, spotify

As per this link: [Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Save to Your Library" in Spotify's desktop app?](https://superuser.com/questions/1263856/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-save-to-your-library-in-spotifys-desktop-app/1280856?noredirect=1#comment1892017_1280856)

The AHK script doesn't seem to work anymore. any updates/new solution to this please?

thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the script uses the ImageSearch command and it searches for an outdated image (a plus sign).  Right now Spotify changed the image to a little heart.  You have to replace that image in order to use it.